# Is there a way to specify only one MockResponse be returned in a SoapUI Mock REST Server?

Tags: rest, soapui, mockrestserviceserver

Newbie to SoapUI.  I am trying to set up a mock REST server to do some testing.  I can see that you can dispatch MockResponses either in a "SEQUENCE" or using a "SCRIPT".  I may have many different responses set up depending on my test cases, but I may only want to return one while I am building out my REST client.  Is there a way to specify which response is sent when the endpoint is hit and only send one response?  Do I have to do this by writing a script?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.  If you set the Dispatch for the MockAction to "Script", you can set the "Default Response" and choose whichever response you want.